# Guidance adjusting a Rust function to handle PrinInt instead of i64

Tags: rust

I have a simple function that encodes an `i64` to a byte stream.

```
fn write_integer(out: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>, value: i64, width: u8) -> Result<()> {
    let mut value = value;

    // while there's stuff outside the 7 LSBs
    while value & !0x7F != 0 {
        // write the 7 LSBs, with the 8th bit set
        out.write_u8((value as u8) & 0x7F | 0x80);

        value >>= 7;
    }

    out.write_u8(value as u8);
    Ok(())
}
```

Instead of reimplementing this to handle *all* integer sizes, I've attempted to make this generic...

```
use num_traits::PrimInt;
fn write_integer_g<T: PrimInt>(out: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>, value: T, width: u8) -> Result<()> {
    let mut value = value;

    // while there's stuff outside the 7 LSBs
    while value & !0x7F != 0 {
        // write the bottom 7 bits, with the 8th bit set
        out.write_u8((value as u8) & 0x7F | 0x80);

        value >>= 7;
    }

    out.write_u8(value as u8);
    Ok(())
}
```

however with less than perfect results..

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/encoded_data.rs:31:23
   |
27 |     fn write_integer_g<T: PrimInt>(out: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>, value: T, width: u8) -> Result<()> {
   |                        - this type parameter
...
31 |         while value & !0x7F != 0 {
   |                       ^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found integer
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `{integer}`
```

Clearly my integer literals need converting to values of type `T`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`num` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num) / [`num-traits` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) traits, such as [`FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html), [`ToPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html), and [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) to convert literals to `T`. Note that the methods in `FromPrimitive` and `ToPrimitive` returns `Option`s, so you might want to handle that better than just unwrapping.

Assuming that [`write_u8()`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.2/byteorder/trait.WriteBytesExt.html#method.write_u8) comes from the [`byteorder` crate](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder)'s [`WriteBytesExt`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.2/byteorder/trait.WriteBytesExt.html) trait, then you can rewrite it like this:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Cursor, Write};
use std::ops::ShrAssign;
// byteorder = "1.4"
use byteorder::WriteBytesExt;
// num-traits = "0.2"
use num_traits::{AsPrimitive, FromPrimitive, PrimInt, Zero};

fn write_integer_g<T>(out: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>, value: T, _width: u8) -> io::Result<()>
where
    T: PrimInt,
    T: FromPrimitive,
    T: AsPrimitive<u8>,
    T: ShrAssign,
{
    let mut value = value;

    let int_127 = T::from_u8(0x7F).unwrap();

    while value & !int_127 != Zero::zero() {
        out.write_u8(value.as_() & 0x7F | 0x80)?;

        value >>= T::from_u8(7).unwrap();
    }

    out.write_u8(value.as_())?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Note that the [`PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.PrimInt.html) requires the [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.Num.html) trait, which in turn requires the [`Zero`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.Zero.html) trait. Which is why we're able to use the methods and associated functions from `Zero`.

So instead of `value & !int_127 != Zero::zero()` you could also do `!(value & !int_127).is_zero()`.

Comment: I prefer this edition, being closer to the generic ideal. Can you share how `value.as_()` returns a `u8`? This bit has me scratching my head, and the docs for `as_` are somewhat terse on the subject.

Comment: @MartinCowie Given that we require that `T: AsPrimitive<u8>`, then `value.as_()` is essentially `self as u8`. If you to to the docs for [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html), specifically down to ["Implementations on Foreign Types"](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html#foreign-impls), then you can see that `AsPrimitive<u8>` is implemented for various types, e.g. `u8`, `i16`, `u64`, `f32`, `isize`, etc. If you click "[src]" on any of these, you can see that the implementation is just `value as u8`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your original code results in an infinite loop if provided with a negative input.

One easy solution is to use [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.14/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) to convert your input into `u64`, then output that:

```
use num_traits::AsPrimitive;
fn write_integer<T: AsPrimitive<u64>>(out: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>, value: T, width: u8) -> Result<()> {
    let mut value: u64 = value.as_();

    // while there's stuff outside the 7 LSBs
    while value & !0x7F != 0 {
        // write the 7 LSBs, with the 8th bit set
        out.write_u8((value as u8) & 0x7F | 0x80);

        value >>= 7;
    }

    out.write_u8(value as u8);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=ef68650ee808a1cbe78db0d2fda80343)

Comment: I know that OP mentions `i64`. However, this solution would produce an incorrect result if `T` is `u128`.